# Node.js resizable buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, buffer

I m new to Node.js and JavaScript.

Suppose I want to write bunch of binary data to the Buffer which represents, strings, integers, etc. in some proprietary encoding, e.g. to represent a body of HTTP request.  But I have no idea how much data I will write, so I don't know how big a buffer I need to allocate.  What is the standard way of doing this in Node.js/JavaScript?

E.g. In Java I would use ByteArrayOutputStream which would resize itself automatically depending on how much data I have written.  I could also wrap it into DataOutputStream if I want to use standard encodings.  But I don't see anything similar in JavaScript.

The standard way it is usually done would to create a wrapper class that would allocate the new buffer of doubled size and copy over the data every time the size limit is hit.  Would that be the best way to do it in Node.js as well?

Or course I could use JavaScript arrays instead of Buffers, since they are resizable, but I m concerned about performance and memory use in this case.

Is there standard way or design pattern for this in Node.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Node.js supports streaming, I think that's what you want - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I read a little about streams.  But it seems that to write binary data, writable.write takes Buffer as an argument.  Does it mean that for every piece of data (integer, string, date, etc.) I have to create a separate buffer?  Seems a little excessive if there are many items.  Or is buffer allocation so optimized that this is the standard way?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. This is beyond my skills. I've never worked this way with streams and buffers